# Find and replace file lines

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file with over 12,000 lines. In that file I need to replace certain lines. 
Some lines begin with a `;`, some have random words, some start with space. However, I am only concerned with the two types of lines I describe below.

I have a line like

```
  SET    avariable:0      ;Comments
```

and I need to replace it to look like

```
  set    aDIFFvariable:0      :Integer      // comments
```

The only CASE that is necessary is in the word `Integer` `I` needs to be capitalized.

I also have

```
  String aSTRING(7)      ;Comment
```

that needs to look like

```
  STRING aSTRING(7)           :array [0..7] of AnsiChar;      // Comments
```

I need to keep all the spacing the same.

**Here is what I have so far**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = File.ReadAllText("C:\\old.txt");
        text = text.Replace("old text", "new text");
        File.WriteAllText("C:\\new.txt", text);
    }
```

I think I need to use REGEX, which I have tried to make for my first example:

`\s\s[set]\s*{4}.*[:0]\s*[;].*` <-- I now know this is invalid - please advise

I need help with properly setting up my program to find and replace those lines. Should I read one line at a time and if it matches then do something? I am confused really as to where to start.

BRIEF pseudo code of what I want to do

```
//open file
//step through file
//if line == [regex] then add/replace as needed
//else, go to next line
//if EOF, close file
```

Comment: First off, the regex you supplied isn't valid, second, please clean up your question and clarify what it is you're wanting; provide clear examples of what you have, what you want to match, and what you want to **not** match. You can also try using a tool like [regex101](http://regex101.com) to test out different regular expressions.

Comment: @r3mus I hope my further explanation is more concise.

Comment: Much better! I'll take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a stab at this separately because each line is so radically different that capturing both in the same expression will be a nightmare.

To match your first example and replace it:

```
String input = "SET    avariable:0      ;Comments";
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\s?(set)\s*(\w+):?(\d)\s+;?(.*)?"))
{
    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s?(set)\s*(\w+):?(\d)\s+;?(.*)?", "$1 $2:$3     :Integer // $4";
}
```

Give that a shot (Play with it here: http://regex101.com/r/zY7hV2)

To match your second example and replace it:

```
String input = "String aSTRING(7)      ;Comments";
if (Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\s?(string)\s*(\w+)\((\d)\)\s*;(.*)"))
{
    input = Regex.Replace(input, @"\s?(string)\s*(\w+)\((\d)\)\s*;(.*)", "$1 $2($3) :array [0..$3] of AnsiChar; // $4";
}
```

And play around with this one here: http://regex101.com/r/jO5wP5

Comment: Thanks! This looks like it's going to work. Any references on how to open a file, read the line, write to same line if necessary, then go to the next one? I cannot find any resources on that?

Comment: How could I do this if I wanted the `aDIFFvaraible` part to just say as is and only add the `:Integer;` and replace the `;` with `//` for the comments?

Comment: Also, I just ran it as is and it didn't work for me :/

Comment: Yeah, it's untested code - I don't have a c# dev environment to test it. You may need to look up my syntax to see if it's right, but the regex101 links provide you the actual expressions to test (note that they use \1 instead of $1 for replaced captures).

Comment: can you elaborate on "replaced captures"

Comment: Read the regex101 links -- they explain the capture groups perfectly. Essentially everything in () gets added to an array for re-use (the $1, $2, etc.). And I'm not sure what exactly you're asking about the `aDIFFvariable` staying the same?

Comment: in my example i gave two different variables for the first matching - i'd like to keep the original variable, not change it to `aDIFFvariable`

Comment: Ah, ok, since I used capture groups here as well, just change `aDIFFvariable` in the regex replace to `$2`, the second captured value. Updated the answer to reflect this too.

Comment: Alright, one last thing. I have some comments that looks like: `(234-2342) blah blah blah` would that be why they aren't matching? I wouldn't think so because of the `(.*)` at the end, correct?

Comment: Right - it's set up to match everything after `;`. Works in the regex101 examples, where are you seeing it fail?

Comment: Yea I tried that too. It works there. For some reason it's not catching a match in C# :/ Guess I'll keep working on it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Np, good luck. You might try removing the `?` from the end of the statement -- maybe C# is interpreting it as non-greedy?